# is_file always returns FALSE on PHP 7/Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have an PHP7/Ubuntu application.

`is_file()` keeps returns `FALSE` regardless if it is a folder or a file. Why? I set RWX permissions for the user runs PHP code (root) and FTP user id used to connect FTP server.

I read multiple posts on stack overflow regarding `file_exist` but none of the suggestions helped me so I create a new post.

```
    $resConnection = ssh2_connect($server, $serverPort) or die('unable to connect');
    if (ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $serverUsername, $serverPassword)) 
{
    $resSFTP_tmp = ssh2_sftp($resConnection);
            $resSFTP = intval($resSFTP_tmp);
            $innerHandle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$resSFTP/.");
        while (false !== ($filename = readdir($innerHandle))) {
        $filepath = "ssh2.sftp://$resSFTP/$filename";
        if(is_file($filepath)) 
            Logger::getInstance()->writeMessage('error', "is_dir True--".$filepath);
        else
            Logger::getInstance()->writeMessage('error', "is_dir False--".$filepath);
}
```

}

`While` loop works fine and it reads through all the files and folders in the base folder. But `is_file` always returns FALSE regardless it is a file or folder. I tried `is_dir` which behaves the same way.

Comment: Give us the actual file path after the variables have been inserted (obviously you can alter parts that give away personal infromation)

Comment: You don't use a file/connection handle in a path.  Show all relevant code.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Surprisingly with `ssh2.*` you *do*…! http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php#refsect1-wrappers.ssh2-examples

Comment: @deceze: Well I'll be damned.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton sftp://41/myfiles/billing.csv is the actual file path and  41 is the handle to the connection.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I added the code to my original post.